# Deno oak websocket must have a method that returns an async iterator

Tags: websocket, deno, oak

I am trying to build up a WebSocket with oak (not the native deno one).
The following code is how I build the server.

```
import {Application, Router, Context, send } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.6.0/mod.ts";

const runWS = async (ctx: Context, next: () => Promise<unknown>) => {
try{
    const ws = await ctx.upgrade();

    ws.onopen = () => {
        chatConnection(ws);
    };
    
    ws.onclose = () => { console.log('Disconnected from the client!');};
}catch{await next();}
}

let sockets = new Map<string, WebSocket>();

const chatConnection = async (ws: WebSocket) => {
console.log('new websocket, ws: ',ws);
const uid = globalThis.crypto.randomUUID();
sockets.set(uid,ws);
console.log('socket: ',sockets);

for await (const ev of ws){
    console.log('ev: ', ev);
 }
}

export const wsRoutes = new Router()
.get('/ws', runWS);
```

But in the for loop (at the end), for ws it says `Type 'WebSocket' must have a '[Symbol.asyncIterator]()' method that returns an async iterator.`. What's the deal with this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is providing you with useful information: the `WebSocket` is not [`AsyncIterable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator), which means that it cannot be used with a [`for await...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of).

> Here is the type documentation for [`WebSocket` in Deno](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/WebSocket). It is (for the most part) the same as the WHATWG standard `WebSocket` that is [documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

If your intention is to respond to incoming [`message` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/message_event), you'll need to attach an event listener:

```ts
webSocket.addEventListener("message", (messageEvent) => {
  // Do something in response to each message event
});
```

---

Additional:

Here's an observation based on the code you've shown, but not in response to your question:

It's probably more ergonomic to store the sockets as the **keys** of your map, and the associated state data in the **values**. (This is the inverse of what you've shown). Here's an example of why:

```ts
import {
  Router,
  type RouterMiddleware,
} from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.6.0/mod.ts";

// You seem to want to log data to the console.
// This function will help you easily log only certain properties of objects:

/**
 * Functional implementation of the type utility
 * [`Pick<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)
 */
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: T,
  keys: readonly K[],
): Pick<T, K> {
  const result = {} as Pick<T, K>;
  for (const key of keys) result[key] = obj[key];
  return result;
}

type SocketData = { id: string };

const socketMap = new Map<WebSocket, SocketData>();

// Do something when a connection is opened
function handleOpen(ev: Event, ws: WebSocket) {
  const socketData: SocketData = { id: window.crypto.randomUUID() };
  socketMap.set(ws, socketData);

  console.log({
    event: pick(ev, ["type"]),
    socketData,
  });
}

// Do something when an error occurs
function handleError(ev: Event, ws: WebSocket) {
  const socketData = socketMap.get(ws);

  console.log({
    event: pick(ev, ["type"]),
    socketData,
  });

  socketMap.delete(ws);
}

// Do something when a connection is closed
function handleClose(ev: CloseEvent, ws: WebSocket) {
  ev.code; // number
  ev.reason; // string
  ev.wasClean; // boolean

  const socketData = socketMap.get(ws);

  console.log({
    event: pick(ev, ["type", "code", "reason", "wasClean"]),
    socketData,
  });

  socketMap.delete(ws);
}

// Do something when a message is received
// Change `unknown` to the type of message payloads used in your application.
// (for example, JSON messages are `string`)
function handleMessage(ev: MessageEvent<unknown>, ws: WebSocket) {
  ev.data; // unknown
  ev.lastEventId; // string
  ev.ports; // readonly MessagePort[]

  const socketData = socketMap.get(ws);
  if (socketData) {
    socketData.id; // string
  }

  console.log({
    event: pick(ev, ["type", "data", "lastEventId", "ports"]),
    socketData,
  });
}

const webSocketMiddleware: RouterMiddleware<"/ws"> = async (ctx, next) => {
  const ws = ctx.upgrade();
  ws.addEventListener("open", (ev) => handleOpen(ev, ws));
  ws.addEventListener("error", (ev) => handleError(ev, ws));
  ws.addEventListener("close", (ev) => handleClose(ev, ws));
  ws.addEventListener("message", (ev) => handleMessage(ev, ws));
  await next();
};

export const router = new Router();
router.get("/ws", webSocketMiddleware);
```

Comment: thank you. your approach fixes some of my issues. but now I have an updated code, and mine is much shorter than yours. I will add my code as an answer so you can take a look. But why the websocket as key when the webscoket is just as follows: `WebSocket {
  url: undefined,
  readyState: 1,
  extensions: undefined,
  protocol: null,
  binaryType: undefined,
  bufferedAmount: NaN
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is my updated code. It avoids the problem entirely

```
import {Application, Router, Context, send } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.6.0/mod.ts";

interface BroadcastObj{
  name: string,
  mssg: string
}

const runWS = async (ctx: Context, next: () => Promise<unknown>) => {
if(!ctx.isUpgradable){
    ctx.throw(501);
}

const uid = globalThis.crypto.randomUUID();
try{
  const ws = await ctx.upgrade();
    ws.onopen = () => {
      chatConnection(ws);
    };
  ws.onmessage = (m) => {
      let mssg = m.data as string;
      if(typeof(mssg) === 'string'){
          chatMessage(JSON.parse(mssg));
      }
  };
  ws.onerror = (e) => {console.log('error occured: ', e);};
  ws.onclose = () => { chatDisconnect(uid);};
}catch{await next();}
}

let sockets = new Map<string, WebSocket>();

const chatConnection = async (ws: WebSocket, uid: string) => {
  await sockets.set(uid,ws);
}

const chatMessage = async (msg: BroadcastObj) => {  
  await sockets.forEach((ws: WebSocket) => {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
  });  
 }

 const chatDisconnect = async (uid: string) => {
   await sockets.delete(uid);
 }

 export const wsRoutes = new Router()
 .get('/ws', runWS);
```